# Return data in Datagrid and proceudre from datareader value

Tags: c#, datareader

I am doing a report for attendance that gets all employees,

basically what I am trying to do, is based on each employee userID returns the attendance based on the dates from the datereader that loops for all userID's  and then place it in the datagridview.

However there is something wrong, it returns only the last UserID, I have tried to place out of the loop but same returns only last userID.

code as below

```
MainClass.Connect();
SqlCommand Com_UserID = new SqlCommand("Select UserID From Tuser",MainClass.MyCon);
MainClass.MyCon.Open();

SqlCommand Com_Attendance = new SqlCommand("SP_EmployeeAttendance",MainClass.MyCon);
Com_Attendance.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Com_Attendance);
DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

SqlParameter P1 = new SqlParameter("@UserID",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50);
P1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input ;
Com_Attendance.Parameters.Add(P1);

Com_Attendance.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DTDeptStartDate.Value;
Com_Attendance.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DTDeptEndDate.Value; ;

SqlDataReader reader = Com_UserID.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
        P1.Value = reader.GetString(0);
    Com_Attendance.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Da.Fill(Ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0];
    reader.NextResult(); 
}
```

Comment: Correct your while loop. like while (reader.Read()) { .. }

Comment: Still wrong. When your datareader will execute it will iterate all records and put the last value in P1.Value

Comment: Yeah, i have tried this one but it shows the first record only , it should pass the value and return it in datagrid and so on next, it has to do with the second proc also

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
while (reader.Read()){
    P1.Value = reader.GetString(0);
    Com_Attendance.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Da.Fill(Ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0];
    reader.NextResult(); 
}
```

**;)** while(condetion)**{** . . . . . **}**

your loop changes only the parameter value and when it reaches the last value executes the nonquery .

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but is now showing only the first userID , it is not getting all user IDs'

Comment: yes because every time in your loop you change the datasource , what you really need (as i guess) is to append the new row to your datatable rows , am I right ?

Comment: reader.NextResult() is not needed because query is returning one result set

Comment: And you need to set the data source of grid outside loop

Comment: Thank you , i have managed to return all data on i put the Datagrid outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

All Data was returned after removing the nextreader and also placing the datagridview datasource outside the loop

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
             P1.Value = reader.GetString(0);
            Com_Attendance.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Da.Fill(Ds);
         }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0];
```